# script fails sometimes when used in cron job

Tags: php, cron

I have this cron command:

```
php <path>/export.php
```

Running at midnight each day. I know the command itself is fired as the files I'm expecting get created, however only the customer file is populated. This is the script:

```
<?php
//============================================================


//- CRON TO BE RUN EVERY DAY 23:59


//============================================================

// be massively careful if you run this on review! 
$sitePath='<removed>';

require_once($sitePath.'<removed>');
set_time_limit(240);

$sage = new Sage();

    $transactionCSV = '';
#-only needed for opening balances
#   $transactionCSV .= $sage->obDebt();
#   $transactionCSV .= $sage->obCredit();
#-

    $transactionCSV .= $sage->ordersCsv();
    $transactionCSV .= $sage->paymentsCsv();
    $transactionCSV .= $sage->creditsCsv();
    $transactionCSV .= $sage->refundsCsv();
        $adj = nl2br(file_get_contents($sitePath.'<removed>'));
    $transactionCSV .= str_replace('<br />', "\r\n", $adj);

    $customerCSV = $sage->customersCsv();

    @file_put_contents($sitePath.'<removed>', '');

    $msg='';
    //var_dump($transactionCSV);
    //exit();

    file_put_contents($sitePath.'<removed>'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv', $customerCSV);    
    file_put_contents($sitePath.'<removed>'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv', $transactionCSV);

    #delete old automated files
    @unlink($sitePath.'<removed>');
    @unlink($sitePath.'<removed>');

    #put in location available via FTP (readonly) as root
    touch($sitePath.'<removed>');
    touch($sitePath.'<removed>');

    file_put_contents($sitePath.'<removed>', $customerCSV); 
    file_put_contents($sitePath.'<removed>', $transactionCSV);

    #allow wood-sage to delete files
    chmod($sitePath.'<removed>', 0777);
    chmod($sitePath.'<removed>', 0777);


    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();                                   // send via SMTP
    $mail->Host     = $mailServer; // SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPDebug = false; //toggle debugging mode true / false
    $mail->Username = $mailBox;  // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = $mailPass; // SMTP password
    $mail->From     = '<removed>';
    $mail->FromName = '<removed>';

    $mail->AddAddress('<removed>', '<removed>');
    $mail->AddCc('<removed>', '<removed>');
    $mail->AddCc('<removed>', '<removed>');
    //for debug purposes
    $mail->AddBcc($webEmail, 'Webmaster');

    $mail->Subject = 'Sage Export: '.date('d/m/Y');

    if(filesize($sitePath.'<removed>'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv')>0){
        $mail->AddAttachment($sitePath.'<removed>'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv');
    }else{
        $msg.='Customer export contains no data.'.chr(10).chr(13);
    }

    if(filesize($sitePath.'<removed>'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv')>0){
        $mail->AddAttachment($sitePath.'<removed>'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv');
    }else{
        $msg.='Transaction export contains no data.';
    }

    $mail->Body=$msg;

    $mail->Send();

exit();

?>
```

When I fire the script manually through the browser everything works. When I use fire manually command in the hosting control panel, everything works. When I set the cron job to fire automatically in a few minutes time, everything works.

In fact the only way I can find to break the script is by putting the command on its normal midnight setting - and I'm completely stumped as to why. For the record, the most recently missed cron job returned 10 rows for the customer file and 499 for the transaction file, and I find it hard to believe so few would cause timeouts or similar errors.

EDIT:

Following advice in the comments I fired the command via SSH and got the following warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(<removed>): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <removed> on line 39
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(<removed>): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <removed> on line 40
PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_lnf9i3q43mrsosmt1dfd17el04, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0
```

Obviously the first two are related to incorrect file permissions, but I've no idea what the other two are.

Comment: Have you tried to run script using the command line? Never run the cron command-line scripts via browsers, they do not share the same environment.

Comment: no - I don't have access. I'm going through our hosting support people to get ssh access switched on.

Comment: What is interesting that as you said some part of the file gets executed. If it was timeout, or some fatal error you would get a regular error log (unless you suppressed it for some reason). Not quite a nice solution but you can create a file and append to the end (in increasing integer for example) after every executed line. Worst case you will see which line the execution breaks on, and if it is the same line every time. Sorry, no better tip, but can lead to solution.

Comment: OK, I now have SSH access. When I run the command I originally posted I get a bunch of permission denied errors when the script interacts with the generated files. Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: You could set 777 rights on the output maps. If that solves the problem you could try to reduce it to 755 or even lower if possible...

Comment: @greengreengrass grant permissions on the files to a cron user, or add  cron user to a group of your current webserver to access the files, or just `chmod -R 0775 <folder>` where you lack access(warning that is a security hole).